# If $|\mbox{Hom}(G_{ab}, Z(G))| = 1$ and $G$ has no abelian direct factor, then $Z(G) \le G'$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G$ be a finite group which has no nontrivial abelian factor, i.e. an abelian normal subgroup $A$ such that there exists some $B \le G$ with $G = A \times B$. Also suppose that the only homomorphism from $G / G'$ to $Z(G)$ is the trivial homomorphism, i.e. $|\operatorname{Hom}(G_{ab}, Z(G))| = 1$, then

> $Z(G) \le G'$.

Do you have any hints how to proof this? I know that every homomorphism to an abelian group factors through $G / G'$, i.e. if $\pi : G \to G/G'$ denotes the natural projection and $\varphi : G \to H$ is a homomorphism into an abelian group $H$, then there exists $\psi : G / G' \to H$ such that $\varphi = \psi \circ \pi$, see [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutator_subgroup). So at least this gives me that every homomorphism $G \to Z(G)$ must be trivial, but what I want is that $\pi(Z(G))$ is already trivial, i.e. 
$$
 Z(G)G' / G \cong Z(G) / (Z(G) \cap G')
$$
vanishes in $G / G'$. But the universal property above does not give me enough information about the embedding of $Z(G)$ in $G / G'$.

So how to solve it?

Comment: If $Z(G) \not\le G'$, then $|Z(G|$ and $|G/G'|$ are not coprime, so there is a nontrivial homomorphism from one to the other. The assumption about not having an abelian direct factor seems irrelevant.

Comment: @DerekHolt This is part of an exercise, before it asked to proof that $|\mbox{Aut}_c(G)| = |\mbox{Hom}(G_{ab}, Z(G))|$, where $\mbox{Aut}_c(G)$ denotes the central automorphisms, i.e. automorphism $\alpha$ such that $g^{-1}g^{\alpha} \in Z(G)$ for all $g$. Is this assumption needed in proving that both sets above have the same cardinality? Because I thought I have a proof without using that $G$ has no nontrivial abelian direct factor, which made me believe it must be used here...

Comment: The equality concerning the size of the group of central automorphisms is true only when $G$ has no abelian direct factor (it is obviously false when $G$ is abelian for example). See http://jlms.oxfordjournals.org/content/s1-44/1/225.extract